# Java: Customizing/Remove name space in Soap Request

Tags: java, soap

I generated classes from the wsdl.

Request I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
       <ns2:acr_JourneySearch xmlns:ns2="https://...../SoapApi/0.1/">
           <access>...
```

Request client required:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="https://......./SoapApi/0.1/"> 
  <S:Body> 
    <ns2:acr_JourneySearch> 
      <access>...
```

How to move ns2 from Body to Envelope?

Comment: It's not quite clear as to what exactly you are trying to achieve and why. Please give more details.

Comment: @VHS Client gave me the link  https://...soapApi?wsdl 
I generated classes:
wsimport -keep -verbose https://...soapApi?wsdl
Send request and get the right response. 
But client said that request must be in the format I described above.
`ns2="https://...../SoapApi/0.1/"` must be not in `<S:Body>` but in `<S:Envelope>`.
I try to google it  but find solutions only for C#.